# Como substituir o valor de uma string a partir de certo caracter?

Tags: angular, typescript

Possuo uma variável chamada `nameImage`.

Ela possui o nome de uma foto. Ex: foto.png

Eu preciso de retirar tudo após o png, ficando apenas o "foto".

Eu tentei:

```
this.formGroup.get('NomeImagem').setValue(this.nameImage)
let teste = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.formGroup.get('NomeImagem')))
teste.replace("./", "")
console.log(teste);
```

Porém eu recebo:

> ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>       --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'
>       |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
>       |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'SubjectSubscription'

Se eu tentar sem o `json.parse(JSON.stringify(...` ele informa que não é possível aplicar o replace na variável teste

Comment: this.formGroup.get('NomeImagem').value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se for algo simples, da para resolver desse jeito.

```js
let photo = "photo.png";

let result = photo.split(".")[0];

console.log(result);
```

Outra alternativa seria:

```js
let photo = "photo.png";

let result = photo.substring(photo, photo.lastIndexOf("."));

console.log(result);
```

Dessa forma você garante que sempre será retornado o nome completo antes do ultimo ponto.

Answer (score 2):

Alternativa para resposta anterior utilizando Regex!

```js
let photo = 'photo.png';

console.log(photo.replace(/\..+/g, ''));
```

Ou:

```js
let photo = "photo.png";

let result = photo.split(".");

console.log(result.shift());
```